# Prove that if $G$ is a graph of order $n \geq 3$ such that $deg$ $v \geq \frac{n}{2}$ for every vertex $v$ of $G$, then $G$ is nonseparable

Tags: graph-theory

I know a nonseparable graph is a connected graph with simply no cut vertices. And that a graph of order at least $3$ is nonseperable if and only if every  two vertices lie on a common cycle.

I'm not sure how to advance from here though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $v$ is a cut vertex. Consider the smallest component $A$ of $G-v$. Each $a \in A$ has at most $(|A|-1)+1=|A| < \frac{n}{2}$ neighbours in $G$, contradiction.

Comment: Is the contradiction that $|A| < \frac{n}{2}$ when originally we assumed that $deg$ $v$ $\geq \frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: The contradiction is that $\deg a < n/2$ when we assumed that $\deg v \geq n/2$ for every vertex.